# Apply different CSS styles of tables with same ID

Tags: html, css

I have tables with the same ID but different information, this is an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="avs">
    <table id="av"><tr><td>User 01</td><td>Paola</td></tr></table>
    <table id="av"><tr><td>User 02</td><td>Roger</td></tr></table>
    <table id="av"><tr><td>User 03</td><td>Jenny</td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to apply a different background color in the first cell for each table so I want to know if it's possible to apply different CSS style for this case. I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
#avs table#av:nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #047AB7;
}

#avs table#av:nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #FF0;
}

#avs table#av:nth-child(3) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #abdd8c;
}
```

I'd like some help.

**UPDATE**

I applied @Sébastién solution but it didn't work, this is my complete code, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="avs">
  <div class="panel-group" id="avancesacor" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-bottom:0px;border-left: 1px solid #047ab7;border-right: 1px solid #047ab7;">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
        <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacor" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">Avance</a>
              </td>
              <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">test test (2018-02-23 10:44:00)</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
          <table class="table" id="avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Archivos</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">
                  <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/SWG0LWmS068erKEEYbaO">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                      <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba2.docx</button>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Páginas traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Palabras traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">85 / 173</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
        <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacor" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Avance</a>
              </td>
              <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">Soledad Lorena Montoya Samamé (2018-02-23 09:34:00)</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
          <table class="table" id="avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Archivos</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">
                  <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/qgkiH6tcQfeJLxvHEnsA">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                      <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba.docx</button>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Páginas traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Palabras traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">26 / 850</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: why do you have tables with same ID?? any reasons???

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal These tables are generated by `while` in PHP for each row in MySQL, it has more information but I just put it simply.

Comment: @NekoLopez Instead of ID use class and check #Sébastien asnwer

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) in HTML MUST be unique in a given document. However classes can be used multiple times.

Just uses classes instead of IDs in your tables:

```css
#avs table.av:nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #047AB7;
}

#avs table.av:nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #FF0;
}

#avs table.av:nth-child(3) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child{
   background: #abdd8c;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="avs">
    <table class="av"><tr><td>User 01</td><td>Paola</td></tr></table>
    <table class="av"><tr><td>User 02</td><td>Roger</td></tr></table>
    <table class="av"><tr><td>User 03</td><td>Jenny</td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is in response to your updated question:

```css
#avs :nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #f90;
}

#avs :nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #0f9;
}

#avs :nth-child(3) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #abdd8c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="avs">
  <div class="panel-group" id="avancesacor" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-bottom:0px;border-left: 1px solid #047ab7;border-right: 1px solid #047ab7;">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
        <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacor" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">Avance</a>
              </td>
              <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">test test (2018-02-23 10:44:00)</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
          <table class="table" id="avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Archivos</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/SWG0LWmS068erKEEYbaO"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba2.docx</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Páginas traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Palabras traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">85 / 173</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
        <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacor" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Avance</a>
              </td>
              <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">Soledad Lorena Montoya Samamé (2018-02-23 09:34:00)</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
          <table class="table" id="avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Archivos</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/qgkiH6tcQfeJLxvHEnsA"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba.docx</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Páginas traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Palabras traducidas</td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">26 / 850</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ever unique id  as

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="avs">
    <table id="av1"><tr><td>User 01</td><td>Paola</td></tr></table>
    <table id="av2"><tr><td>User 02</td><td>Roger</td></tr></table>
    <table id="av3"><tr><td>User 03</td><td>Jenny</td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ad for accessing to child you could use nth-of-type selector eg:

```
  #avs:first-of-type {
      background: red;
  }

  #avs:first-of-type {
      background: red;
  }

  #avs:nth-of-type(2) {
      background: yellow;
  }

  #avs:nth-of-type(3) {
      background: blue;
  }
```